# Bad value http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=120x100&center=

Tags: php, google-maps, validation

When i did a page validation i got the following error. Please help me as i couldn't find the answers.

**Bad value http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=120x100&center=175-Stanley-St-West Melbourne-VIC-3003&zoom=13&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyCF83pgZddXnerlPQHxWh6dhersl_wDI1Y for attribute src on element img: Illegal character in query: not a URL code point.
…ters" alt="Worboys Plumbing Pty Ltd-Melbourne VIC 3000-Plumbers & Gasfitters" >**

Syntax of IRI reference:
Any URL. For example: /hello, #canvas, or http://example.org/. Characters should be represented in NFC and spaces should be escaped as %20.

Answer (score 0):

**"Syntax of IRI reference: Any URL. For example: /hello, #canvas, or http://example.org/. Characters should be represented in NFC and spaces should be escaped as %20."**

```
%20 = spaces
```

In between St-West and Melbourne, you can see a space not being escaped properly.

Correct Link: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=120x100&center=175-Stanley-St-West%20Melbourne-VIC-3003&zoom=13&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyCF83pgZddXnerlPQHxWh6dhersl_wDI1Y